# Visual Studio Ordered Tests - Different Projects

Tags: visual-studio-2013, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I have created a number of (separate) CodedUI projects within Visual Studio 2013, in order to test the basic functions of a website.

Test-cases are created as separate projects, as I expect some (or all?) of them to change over time, and thus to ensure 'modularity' of capture for ease of subsequent maintenance.

Now, I see I can easily create an Ordered Test within each project, which will allow the same test-case to be run and re-run as many times as I wish; But, it's not obvious to me how I can create an Ordered Test whereby I can add different test-cases created as different projects. Certainly, not directly.

Is it possible?

Also, can I rename the Ordered Test list and save it to a separate folder where I can store differing Ordered Tests to test functionality, as I wish?

Ideally, I'd like to create an Ordered Test external to any specific project, so I can go into any project I wish and add whatever tests I wish, as the test-environment is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

you should have created a single project for your application. To ensure 'modularity', coded ui has given us the option of creating different UI Maps within a same project. Each UI MAP will represent a module of your application. This approach will give you easy maintenance and it will also help you to create ordered test cases which contain test cases from different UI Maps.
for more details please see this link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398056.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks

Yes, I sort of see that. And I guess it's easy enough to move the code to become separate 'solutions' within a 'project'.

However, I want to work with TFS server too, so will look at the MTM route as well.

But it may be that I need my captured CodedUI to be 'solutions' within a single project too - though I really want my modules to be 'stand-alone' projects for safe-keeping.

Will investigate further.